# XMLUNIT ignore xmlns?

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit

Try to get this two XML like similar (want to ignore xmlns) and differer element sequance but not working correctly for me. If remove xmlns, doc are simmilr. 
I am Using XMlUnit 1.5

```
String s1 = "<root xmlns=\"http:example.com\">"
                        +"<Date/>"
                        +"<Time/>"
                     +"</root>";

String s2 = "<root>"
                      +"<Time/>"
                      +"<Date/>"
                   +"</root>";
myDiff = XMLUnit.compareXML(s1,s2);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things you need to do:

- in order to ignore the different namespaces you need to provide a `DifferenceListener` that downgrades the difference
- the default `ElementQualifier` used by `Diff` is `ElementNameQualifier` that only compares elements with the same local name and namespace URI.  You need to override this one as well.

  ```
  Diff xmlDiff = new Diff(s1, s2);
  xmlDiff.overrideElementQualifier(new ElementNameQualifier() {
          @Override
          protected boolean equalsNamespace(Node control, Node test) {
              return true;
          }
      });
  xmlDiff.overrideDifferenceListener(new DifferenceListener() {
          @Override
          public int differenceFound(Difference diff) {
              if (diff.getId() == DifferenceConstants.NAMESPACE_URI_ID) {
                  return RETURN_IGNORE_DIFFERENCE_NODES_IDENTICAL;
              }
              return RETURN_ACCEPT_DIFFERENCE;
          }
          @Override
          public void skippedComparison(Node arg0, Node arg1) { }
      });
  ```

creates a "similar" result.  In order get an "identical" result you'd also need to downgrade `CHILD_NODELIST_SEQUENCE_ID` differences.